# Regular Expressions, trying to match no more than one period?

Tags: java, regex

Using: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

and testing the regular expression(s):

```
\.{0,1} 

(?=.*?\.{0,1})
```

I was referencing this: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html, and trying other combinations but nothing is working the way I want.

For instance, for test inputs and matching, I am expecting..

```
lo.cat.tion - no match
location - match
loc_ation - match
loc.ation - match
```

But it's telling me nothing matches at all.  What am I doing it wrong here ? :(

Comment: which regex are you using to match the top one or bottom one ?

Comment: I was just giving both as an example of some things I was trying.

Comment: did you want to allow more than one underscore?

Comment: anything else is allowed, just no more than one period.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/iI1wM4/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to match only one or no dot in your whole input can be achieved as follows:

```
String[] input = {
                "lo.cat.tion", // - no match
                "location", // - match
                "loc_ation", // - match
                "loc.ation" // - match
        };
//                           | start of input
//                           || non dots, 0 or more
//                           ||    | 1 dot or nothing (dot requires \\escaping here)
//                           ||    |   | non dots, 0 or more
//                           ||    |   |    | end of input
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[^.]*\\.?[^.]*$");
for (String s: input) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    // we use "matches" instead of "find", to match the entire input here, 
    // although in this context both methods yield equivalent results
    System.out.printf("Matches for \"%s\"? %b%n", s, m.matches());
}
```

**Output**

```
Matches for "lo.cat.tion"? false
Matches for "location"? true
Matches for "loc_ation"? true
Matches for "loc.ation"? true
```

Comment: Technically you don't need the `?` since you're using the star repetition operator. http://regex101.com/r/iI1wM4/1

Comment: @hwnd yes you do. Marks dot as 0 or 1 instance. We want to match inputs with no dots at all as well.

Comment: @hwnd just run it. It won't.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.. Thank you!

So, ^ starts looking at the start of the line, [^.] <- What is this ? Could you explain what you did there?

Comment: @user3380255 You're welcome. Let me comment on the Pattern - just a sec.

Answer (score 1):

A simple program using `String#indexOf()` method. Simply count the number of dots(decimal point) present in the string.

```
public static boolean isValid(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    int fromIndex = -1;
    while ((fromIndex = s.indexOf(".", fromIndex + 1)) != -1) {
        count++;
        if (count > 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

...

System.out.println(isValid("lo.cat.tion"));  // false
System.out.println(isValid("location"));     // true
System.out.println(isValid("loc_ation"));    // true
System.out.println(isValid("loc.ation"));    // true
```

---

Alternatively use `String.matches()` method without using `Pattern` or `Matcher` API.

```
String regexPattern = "[^.]*\\.?[^.]*";
System.out.println("lo.cat.tion".matches(regexPattern)); // false
System.out.println("location".matches(regexPattern));    // true
System.out.println("loc_ation".matches(regexPattern));   // true
System.out.println("loc.ation".matches(regexPattern));   // true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allow more than one dot in a string then you could try the below look-ahead

```
(?=^[^.]*\.{0,1}[^.]*$).*
```

OR

```
(?=^[^.]+\.{0,1}[^.]+$).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fN3zU5/19)

Answer (score 0):

use this regex:

```
^[^.]*(?:(?:\.[^\.]*){0,1})$
```

took a lot of time to figure this one out

demo here: http://regex101.com/r/kP4mF3/1